# ORACLE SQL: Look for last row in column then update data from another data without affecting older data

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm currently learning to code in Oracle SQL. Referring to example on photo i attached, I would like to my script to look for last date in Table A, if the date (Table A) is less than date in Table B, then insert only the latest date data from Table B to A without affecting older date data in Table A.

[image: table example].

The reason is because Table B data is store by month, meaning that month Jan data will be purge out when going to Feb. So the purpose of Table A is to retain all the data i want from Table B.

And how do i embedded the script in table so that it autorun everyday?

Comment: Please show a sample from both tables both before and after the insert operation.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into TableA (
select * from TableB where date >(select max(date) from TableA)
);
```

Comment: Hi @NaveenArora I modify your code and now it work but this `--and sales not in (select sales from TableA)` couldn't work so i have to disable this line. This is the working code


`insert into TableA a (date, sales)
select * from TableB b where date >(select max(date) from TableA)
--and sales not in (select sales from TableA)
);`

Comment: I added second condition just to make sure that only latest data should be inserted. Anyway if that is not required then it can be removed.

Comment: @LeoEY I have removed that. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the SELECT statement are useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name removing parentheses around select gives error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Sorry. I thought you are talking about this select: (select max(date) from TableA)

Comment: Yes You are Right, parentheses around the SELECT * from TableB... can be removed.

Comment: What are the way to run this script without using Job Scheduler? I try Oracle Job Scheduler but it seem like i dont have privilege to schedule job. Is there anyway to automate the data update everyday?

Comment: If you are using linux then you can write shell script and put that in Crond service to run it everyday.

Comment: @LeoEY . . . This could insert more than one row, which you don't seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in Oracle 12c+, you can use:

```
insert into a (date, sales)
    select date, sales
    from b
    where b.date > (select max(a.date) from a)
    order by date desc
    fetch first 1 row only;
```

The `order by` and `fetch` ensure that only the most recent row is inserted.

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery:

```
insert into a (date, sales)
    select date, sales
    from (select b.*, row_number() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
          from b
          where b.date > (select max(a.date) from a)            
         ) b
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If you run this code every day, you will just end up inserting every row of `b` into `a`.  I assume you are aware of that.